# C++ allocator for std::wstring_convert

Tags: c++, performance, c++17

In my application, I'm using `std::wstring_convert` to convert `std::string` into `std::u32string`. As this is very frequently done, I want to use a custom allocator to improve performance (and to learn more about C++).

Therefore, I wrote a custom allocator which allocates 2 blocks of memory with a fixed size of 300 (seems sufficient for my cases) at construction of std::wstring_convert. What do you think about this allocator?

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

template<class T> struct MemorySlot {
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    bool used;
};

template<class T> class StringConverterAllocator {
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using char_type = T;

        StringConverterAllocator(){
            for (auto& memorySlot : memorySlots) {
                auto deleter = [](T* ptr){::operator delete(ptr, ALLOCATED_SIZE * sizeof(T));};
                memorySlot.ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(ALLOCATED_SIZE * sizeof(T))), deleter);
                memorySlot.used = false;
            }
        }
        
        template<class U> explicit StringConverterAllocator(const StringConverterAllocator<U>& src){
            assert(sizeof(U) == sizeof(T));
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < memorySlots.size(); ++i) {
                memorySlots[i].ptr = src.memorySlots[i].ptr;
                memorySlots[i].used = src.memorySlots[i].used;
            }
        }

        T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
            if (n <= ALLOCATED_SIZE) {
                for (auto& memorySlot : memorySlots) {
                    if (!memorySlot.used) {
                        memorySlot.used = true;
                        return memorySlot.ptr.get();
                    }
                }
            }
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
        }
        
        void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) {
            for (auto& memorySlot : memorySlots) {
                if (memorySlot.ptr.get() == p) {
                    memorySlot.used = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            return ::operator delete(p, n * sizeof(T));
        }

    private:
        static constexpr std::size_t ALLOCATED_SIZE = 300;
        std::array<MemorySlot<T>, 2> memorySlots;
};

typedef std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t, StringConverterAllocator<char32_t>, StringConverterAllocator<char>> WStringConvertA;
typedef std::basic_string<char32_t, std::char_traits<char32_t>, StringConverterAllocator<char32_t>> U32StringA; //identical to std::u32string but with a custom allocator

/////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// TESTING PART
/////////////////////////////////
void* operator new(std::size_t sz) {
    std::cout<<"    - New operator called"<<std::endl;
    return std::malloc(sz);
}

int main() {
    {
        std::cout<<"Without allocator:"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"  - Init phase:"<<std::endl;
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> stringConvert;
            
        std::cout<<"  - Execution phase:"<<std::endl;
        std::u32string u32Text = stringConvert.from_bytes("myString...");
        std::u32string copyText = u32Text;
    }
    
    {
        std::cout<<"With allocator:"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"  - Init phase:"<<std::endl;
        WStringConvertA stringConvert;
            
        std::cout<<"  - Execution phase:"<<std::endl;
        U32StringA u32Text = stringConvert.from_bytes("myString...");
        U32StringA copyText = u32Text;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`assert(sizeof(U) == sizeof(T));`
Try `static_assert` instead since these types are known at compile time!

`typedef std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t, StringConverterAllocator<char32_t>, StringConverterAllocator<char>> WStringConvertA;`
Prefer `using` to legacy `typedef`.

```
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < memorySlots.size(); ++i) {
                memorySlots[i].ptr = src.memorySlots[i].ptr;
                memorySlots[i].used = src.memorySlots[i].used;
            }
```

Why not just use one assignment `memorySlots = src.memorySlots` ?

You didn't define the normal copy constructor too.  I recall that a template that matches isn't *the* copy constructor... I'll have to check what C++17 or later says about it.

---

Your `allocate` and `deallocate` are coding loops instead of using std algorithms.

---

I worry that the `shared_ptr`, which uses atomic primitives to be thread safe, will eat away the performance benefit you get from writing a custom allocator.  How good is the built-in memory allocator (depends on the OS)?  It might be doing something like that already with look-aside pools and thread-local cacheing.

---

Standard advice you'll see all over CodeReviews:

[⧺SL.io.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl) Don't use `endl`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Indeed, I should find a better solution to avoid shared_ptr usage. What is the problem with coding loops ? Do you think it is better to use std::for_each ? What is the advantage ?

Comment: Generally I agree with you about `endl`, however, there is the odd case where you want to write the new line character and then flush the output buffer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw yes, and since its very presence will trip up code reviewers forever forward, when you mean that write it as a call to `flush`.

Comment: @user249967 The answer to that fills numerous hour-long seminars, including presentations by Strustrup himself.  To start with, consider the cognitive load when reading it; one has to figure out what the code _does_, examining in the low-level statements.  It's a higher level to just write _find_, _fill_, _move_, or whatnot.  Second, such detailed code could contain mistakes, and the library code may be carefully optimized.  I don't find `std::for_each` to be particularly handy though, since it doesn't do anything other than the loop itself -- and C++ now has a range-based for loop natively.

Comment: For your `allocate` and `deallocate` I don't mean using `for_each` instead of a built-in `for` loop.  I mean not writing a loop at all, but using `std::find`.  The first one is `std::ranges::find (memorySlots, true, &MemorySlot::used)`.  The second one is `std::ranges::find (memorySlots, p, &MemorySlot::ptr)`.